# Java: find sub sequences

Tags: java

Required to find the first occurrence in this sequence and return position of this occurrence.
I find [LazySeq lib in github](https://github.com/nurkiewicz/LazySeq).

Comment: If the second sequence is a short one, you can use naive algorithm, that just takes the last n (= length) symbols and compares is with the second sequence. But be aware of long sequences! This algorithm would work for `O (n * m)`, where `n` - length of the second sequence and `m` - length of the part of the first sequence, that we have to read before we reach the first occurence.

Comment: Out of curiosity , how will you plan to store the first sequence in your java program??

Comment: @apomene Sure, it should be some `Supplier <Integer>` or smth like this.

Comment: Dmitry Ginzburg: The second sequence can be any length.

Comment: apomene: for exampele LazySeq object. And after I'm planed use filter to find position of subsequence, but not sure that this is possible.

Comment: Then you may use some better [string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).

Comment: @bdhvevhvonof you cannot use filter for doing this as filter can be used only for elements one-by-one, not the whole scope.

Comment: Need more code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work:

```
// The concept of an infinite sequence is that there is always a next.
abstract static class InfiniteIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return true;
    }

}

// The digits of all decimal numbers concatenated.
static class InfiniteDigits extends InfiniteIterator<Character> {

    // The number we are working on.
    int n = 1;
    // The String version of n
    String s = Integer.toString(n);
    // Where we are in the string.
    int i = 0;

    @Override
    public Character next() {
        if (i >= s.length()) {
            s = Integer.toString(++n);
            i = 0;
        }
        return s.charAt(i++);
    }

}

// Finds a String in a stream of characters.
static class StringFinder {

    // The source of the stream.
    final Iterator<Character> source;
    // Track of the past.
    final StringBuilder traversed = new StringBuilder();

    public StringFinder(Iterator<Character> source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public int find(final String find) {
        // How far we've matched.
        int matched = 0;
        // How many characters we've passed.
        int passed = 0;
        // Walk the source until we get a match.
        while (matched < find.length()) {
            Character next = source.next();
            traversed.append(next);
            if (next == find.charAt(matched)) {
                // Still matching!
                matched += 1;
            } else {
                // Mismatch.
                passed += matched + 1;
                matched = 0;
            }
        }
        // Want 1-based position.
        return passed + 1;
    }
}

private void test(String string) {
    StringFinder finder = new StringFinder(new InfiniteDigits());
    System.out.println("'" + string + "' found at " + finder.find(string) + " traversed " + finder.traversed);
}

public void test() {
    test("567");
    test("1112");
    test("765");
}
```

NB: The `traversed` field is there for debugging. I would suggest you remove it before you test in anger.

Prints:

```
'567' found at 5 traversed 1234567
'1112' found at 12 traversed 123456789101112
'765' found at 1619 traversed 1234567891011121314...85695705715725735745755765
```